# Can I format new MacBook hard drive from OSX DVD?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, bootable-disk

I have to install a fresh new drive into my MacBook pro 2009.

I haven't formatted yet, nor do I have a USB dock to do so from my current osx installation.

If I install the new drive and boot from the osx DVD that came with my Mac, will be able to do what's necessary to get every running ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have full access to the Disk Utility program from within the installer process, so you can partition and format to your hearts content.